# Horizontally aligned Elements overlapping

Tags: wpf

[image]

When i resize window the elements are overlapping, i have set the alignments left and right so that on resize they stay at their positions.

here's the code, on resize `start private exam` should not overlap `setting` and should stop before `setting`, please guide.

**(edit) Full code & explanation added** I was hoping if window is resized, and other control hits other control, it should either stop resizing or provide scroll, by not overlapping on other controls.

I have a `stackpanel banner` with picture in it. and i'm not sure how but no other control overlaps it when window resize vertically. But besides all controls are overlapping on each other when resize and out of space.

```
<Window x:Class="Engine.ExamWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ExamWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid x:Name="GridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="105" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Background="Lavender" Grid.Row="0" >
            <MenuItem Header="_Exam" >
                <MenuItem Header="_Start practice" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Start Virtual." />
                <MenuItem Header="_Finish" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Exit" Click="menuExamExit_Click" />
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem Header="_Navigation" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Tools" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
        </Menu>

        <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelBanner" Grid.Row="1" />

        <Grid x:Name="GridContent" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <TabItem Header="All Exams">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0">No history available</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Practice Exams">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0">No history available</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Virtual Exams">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0">No history available</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">Setting</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,120,0">Start Private Exam</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">Start Virtual Exam</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0">Contact Support</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: There are few ways to solve your issue but what is your goal? What should happen if items don't fit in given width?

Answer (score 1):

When the width of the Grid containing the three TextBlocks is too narrow to fit the actual text, of course there will be something overlapping.

You should first decide what to do. Typically, when there's no enough space for a certain text, it is truncated, often with the ellipsis (...).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx

If you like that, just modify the XAML as follows:

```
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="10,0,0,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">Setting</TextBlock>
```

Comment: it says error: requested value "CharacterEllipsis" not found, it only gives 3 iems, wrap, nowrap, wrapwithoverflow

Comment: Huh? Follow the link and see the example. Are you using WPF or what else?

Comment: I think it's the `TextTrimming`, rather than `TextWrapping` that you want to set (for "CharacterEllipsis").

Comment: Took me a minute to spot it =D

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will vary depending on how you'd like your window/text to appear; once you start shrinking your window, you'll run out of space to fit all that text on the screen (as you're aware).

The most simply solution may well be setting  the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties on your window, so you can restrict just how small users are allowed to make your application.

You can also decrease the font size, or set a `MinWidth` on the `Grid` that houses the text (although you'll still have a problem once your window becomes too small), and a few other options.

It will entirely depend on your desired result.

Comment: ok the window minwidth seems good choice, and i'll use that. but same effect is being applied on `height` when resize. other controls are overlaping, is there any way to restric the resize when a control is hit

Comment: `MinHeight` should do the height. These properties should apply to any control in your design, but again, it depends on how exactly you want your control to behave once your run out of room.